# How to protect website against attacks

Tags: wordpress, security, nginx

I have a VPS on digital ocean and running wordpress website. My server always crashes down everyday because of attacks. I have Wordfence plugin installed on my site but it is not sufficient. I dont know how to solve this issue.

I always get 502 gateway error. How can i protect my server from attacks?

[My error log](http://textuploader.com/53z0j)

[Failed logins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu7kd.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Your question is too wide, you should be more specific. There are countless tutorials, like [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-security-measures-to-protect-your-servers), about how to do that.

Comment: Thank you Ivan but as i am new to server management i dont know how to give you specific info
i added my error log 
would it give any clue?

Answer (score 0):

According your logs, you have problem with php-fpm. If you use smallest size droplet(512Mb RAM), then php-fpm process could be killed by OOM-killer, check you system logs for this(`dmesg | grep kill`).

To resolve this problem you should add swap to system([tutorial for ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)), it would help to prevent regular php-fpm kills due out of memory.

Comment: Thank you Alexander
as you said i am using 512 mb ram droplet which is smallest one. but my blog is getting limited traffic .here is my ufw log 
[ufw log](http://txt.do/53zcj )

and here is my syslog
[syslog](http://txt.do/53zcf ) 

where should i look at to find the issue?

Comment: @malcom it's full `dmesg` output?

Comment: @malcom it's too short, usually it's store more then 8 seconds of data.

Comment: i have only this file :( i think my website is getting hit

look at wordfence results

http://prntscr.com/ble4su